# Define identical treatment of private subclass members in superclass

Tags: java, inheritance, private, abstract

I've got this parent class:

```
abstract class Parent {
  abstract int getX();
}
```

And two different subclass implementations:

```
class AgnosticChild extends Parent {

  private int x = 5;

  @Override
  int getX() {
    return x;
  }
}

class ManipulativeChild extends Parent {

  private static int x = 5;

  ManipulativeChild() {
    x++;
  }

  @Override
  int getX() {
    return x;
  }
}
```

Both `getX()` implementations are identical. Is there any way to get rid of this redundancy while keeping the different implementations for `x`? Assume that the `getX()` implementation is a lot more elaborate in practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the two implementations are not identical - one accesses a static field, and the other accesses an instance field.  So although they look identical, they're functionally very different; and there's no opportunity for re-use here, without changing the behaviour of your classes.

Answer (score 2):

You could pull up the int variable to Parent class and implement `getX` method there

```
abstract class Parent {
    private int x;

    public Parent(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

}

class AgnosticChild extends Parent {

    public AgnosticChild() {
        super(5);
    }


}

class ManipulativeChild extends Parent {


    ManipulativeChild() {
        super(6);
    }
}
```

**Update:** The upper code snippet only equal to your code if you want to declare the `x` in `ManipulativeChild` as non-static field. Otherwise these are two different implementation and cannot be refactored in the proposed way.

Comment: According to the OP's code, x is static in `AgnosticChild` but not in `ManipulativeChild` --> it cannot be the same `x`

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I added the limitation in my answer